# Entity Framework 6 / Firebird database provider compatibility issue in Visual Studio 2013 Prof

Tags: entity-framework-6, firebird

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and .Net 4.5 on Windows 7-x64.  I have Firebird 2.5.4-x64 installed.

I know that others are able to use Firebird with Entity Framework 6, and I figured out several issues on my own by reading lots of blogs and stackoverflow posts.  But I've tried everything I can think of and I am totally stuck.  I figured before I gave up completely on using Firebird, I'd see if someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

There seems to be a lot of outdated information on how to configure firebird within visual studio, and I've tried lots of variations of them, but here is what I think was the correct process:

- I installed FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient-4.6.1.0.msi.
- I verified that it updated GAC:

  ```
  The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c, processorArchitecture=MSIL
  Number of items = 1
  ```
- I verified that it updated  in machine.config files:

  ```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  ```
- I installed DDEXProvider-3.0.1.0.msi
- I verified that entries were added to the registry and that the paths were correct
- I created a new `Class Library` project
- I installed the following Nuget packages:

  ```
    <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EntityFramework.Firebird" version="4.6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" version="4.6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  ```
- I verified updates were made to the App.config file.  (Besides trying the default App.config file below, I also tried using one like [the one in this blog](http://blog.cincura.net/233426-entity-framework-6-with-firebird/))

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      </configSections>
      <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
        <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
  </configuration>
  ```
- I successfully built the project
- I successfully added a connected to an existing Firebird db (the Firedbird data provider and data source showed up in the options)
- I tried to adde a new `ADO.Net Entity Data Model`, using `EF Designer from database` option and the data connection I had just added
- When I clicked `Next` I got this error:

  ```
  Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however,
  an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could
  not be found for your data connection. If you have already installed a
  compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your project before
  performing this action. Otherwise, exit this wizard, install a compatible
  provider, and rebuild your project before performing this action.
  ```

If I don't install the EntityFramework Nuget package, there is a EF 5.0 option that is enabled and I don't get this error when I use 5.0.  (But I'd really like to use 6.x instead!)

Does anyone have any idea how I can get past this error?  Is there something else I can look at or do to try to figure it out?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! I finally figured out what was going on. I was using `Manage NuGet Packages...` to install the packages and it seemed like everything installed with no problem.  I was following another tutorial which had me use the Package Manager Console & I got an error because my project was located on a Network Share.  So, I wondered if perhaps the firebird stuff was having similar issues.

Sure enough, when I ran `install-package entityframework.firebird` in the console, I saw errors!  That would explain why my app.config file did not get updated.  And now the `an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could
not be found` message makes total sense.  It's too bad the `Manage NuGet Packages...` doesn't pop up error messages when something goes wrong!  That would have saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `entityFramework` section in configuration with provider registered. When you install the `EntityFramework.Firebird` the settings should be added.

```xml
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

You can see the whole `App.config` [here](https://github.com/cincuranet/EF6_Firebird/blob/master/CodeFirst/App.config).

Also the [repository](https://github.com/cincuranet/EF6_Firebird/) might give you head start, although it's just result of basically installing NuGet packages. More details [here](http://blog.cincura.net/233472-entity-framework-6-with-firebird-updated/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to help @cincura.net.  I thought it was odd that after installing the nuget packages, the App.config seemed to missing stuff.  That's why I mentioned in my question that I had tried a different config file too (in fact it was by the same guy you referenced).  In hopes that there was something slightly different than I had tried before, I copied/pasted the one you linked to into my project, but it did not have any effect.